# Provisioning and build issue

Tags: ios, xcode

After updating some code on a iPhone application in XCode, I tried to build a distribution version of the application. I built it in exactly the same way yesterday and it worked. Heres what happened this time:

> Xcode cannot run using the selected device. No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.

I checked the version numbers in Xcode and those seem fine: iOS Deployment Target is 5.1, Base SDK is Latest iOS (iOS6).

On checking the Organizer for Provisioning Profiles, I clicked 'Refresh' and the following error message came up: "No value was provided for the parameter 'appIdName'.".

I've tried re-issuing a distribution profile but this hasn't worked.

Does anyone have any ideas? I've checked previous threads and none seem to apply. Possibly because I've missed something?

Answer (score 1):

- Clean up your project using Clean, Clean folders, Delete derived data.
- Delete all schemes from 'manage schemes'. Recreate them, and build using any of them that contains a version of iPhone simulator (the one that worked earlier).

If that doesn't work, try this:

- Clean up your project using Clean, Clean folders, Delete derived data.
- Using your favorite editor, try clearing all the profile strings (lines starting with Provisioning Profile) from your project.pbxproj file (the one that you see when you open your xcode project using archive utiltiy).
- Then restart xcode. Select the profile using automatic profile selector and build using an iphone simulator scheme. If no profiles show up, refresh XCode organizer for your profiles to download from apple portal, and then try building again.